# How to prevent transition-delay when reversd

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a `<div>` , I want to double its `width` and `height` when `hover` .

But I want the `width` to be transitioned first and then `height` .

And when reversing (mouse moved out), I want the `height` to be transitioned first, then `height` .

(Just an epitome of complex transitions, to demonstrate the issue)

```css
.box {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s 1s, height 1s 0s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the example above, if I remove the mouse when transitioning `height` , everything is OK.

But if I remove the mouse when transitioning `width` , I have to wait `1s` which is the `transition-duration` of `height` part (actually because of the `transition-delay`) before the reverse transition of `width` starts, which leads to awful result when the transition queue is complex.

Vice versa, if I `hover` the element again when transitioning `height` backwards, I have to wait for `1s` until I can see `height` animating, because of the `1s` delay.
I'm expecting to see `width` transitioning backwards immediately after I remove the mouse.

---

Here is an example of a complex transition queue:
[CSS Gradient neon button with hover effect](https://codepen.io/xsjctony/pen/YzLKYrB)

---

Is there any way to prevent the problem just by CSS transitions?

Comment: Have you tried using a keyframe animation instead?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
  function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "200px";
    x.style.width = "200px";
  }

  function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "100px";
    x.style.width = "100px";
  }
</script>
<div class="box" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)"></div>
```

and then simply remove the `.box:hover` css completely

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a CSS-only solution